# No Sound Ubuntu - Intel C230 Audio Controller Driver

Tags: drivers, sound

I recently dual booted Ubuntu on my 21.5" 2017 iMac, and there is no sound outputting from the internal speakers. I have tried everything I could that I found on the internet, and came to the conclusion I need a driver for the sound car in my computer.
When I type `sudo lspci`, the audio devices come up as:

`00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family HD Audio Controller (rev 31)`
and
 `01:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Baffin HDMI/DP Audio [Radeon RX 550 640SP / RX 560/560X]`

`sudo alsamixer` outputs

[image: Alsamixer]

What should I do to fix this issue?

Comment: Hey Christian Prince! Which Ubuntu version are you using?

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS I believe. Linux Kernel 5.8 Generic if it matters.